# PrivateKey is missing when importing a certificate

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, certificate, x509certificate

I've been using the following cdmlet to import PFX certificates into a Windows Docker container:

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $CertificatePath -CertStoreLocation $location -Password $securePassword
```

This was working just fine until 2 days ago (might be related to [CVE-2021-1731](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/en-US/vulnerability/CVE-2021-1731)?), when some tests started to fail with the following error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Key not valid for use in specified state.

Running `Get-ChildItem Cert:\ -Recurse | Format-List *` I was able to spot some differences between the previous and the latest version of the Docker image.

In the previous (working version):

```
 HasPrivateKey            : True
 PrivateKey               : System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
```

In the latest (failing version):

```
 HasPrivateKey            : True
 PrivateKey               :
```

I'm trying to install certificates in both the `LocalMachine` and `CurrentUser` stores. Based in other SO posts and came up with this as an alternative to `Import-PfxCertificate ...`:

```
$CertificatePath = "..." 
$securePassword = "..."

$StoreLocations=@()
$StoreLocations += 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My'
$StoreLocations += 'Cert:\LocalMachine\Root'
$StoreLocations += 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My'
$StoreLocations += 'Cert:\CurrentUser\Root'

foreach($location in $StoreLocations){
    $certificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
    $certificate.Import($CertificatePath, $securePassword, "PersistKeySet,MachineKeySet")

    $storeLocation = $location.Split("\")[1] # e.g. LocalMachine
    $storeName = $location.Split("\")[2] # e.g. My
    $store = New-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store($storeName, $storeLocation)
    $store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::"ReadWrite")
    $store.Add($certificate)
    $store.Close() 
}
```

This seems to work fine for `LocalMachine` store but it fails for `CurrentUser` (Access Denied).

I tried also setting differents depending on the store, with no luck:

```
if($location -Match "CurrentUser"){
    $certificate.Import($CertificatePath, $securePassword, "PersistKeySet,UserKeySet")
}
elseif($location -Match "LocalMachine"){
    $certificate.Import($CertificatePath, $securePassword, "PersistKeySet,MachineKeySet")
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks ok. `HasPrivateKey` returns `$true`, so private key is there. The fact that `PrivateKey` property is empty means that key is stored in Key Storage Provider instead of legacy CSP. In fact, `X509Certificate2.PrivateKey` property is obsolete since .NET 4.6.

Comment: But what can explain the changes in the certificates? These are probably the cause of the errors: `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Key not valid for use in specified state.`

Comment: where you get this exception?

Comment: running .NET tests. These certificates are installed into Docker images that we use as Azure DevOps build agents.

Comment: It still doesn't answer my previous question -- where? Can you provide code snippet and point to a line that causes exception?

Comment: it might take me a while to get a code snippet as I'm not the owner of the code. I'll get back to you when I can

Comment: You may need to start a new question on this exception issue.